# cmd line mac gives me weird output when trying to install composer

Tags: php, cmd, composer-php, homebrew

It's probably a very simple solution, i tried installing composer (without succes). So i tried to give it a different approach and tried multiple ways to install it including a new version of PHP7 / (7.1). But could not find succes. Cmd line keeps giving me the 5.3.6. version. So i tried homebrew and then something went wrong. Now when i type in 'install composer' i get this output.
`usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...`

Can anyone help me get out of this mode or whatever it is? And maybe as a plus give me some help on why my version wont change when i install PHP 7 via cmd line or MAMP?

Much appreciated.

Jimi

Comment: do you mean "composer install" instead of "install composer"?

Comment: that was the problem unfortunately haha, i needed 'composer install' instead of install composer.. I fixed it.

Comment: ill make an answer that you can accept, if you dont mind :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use "composer install" instead of "install composer" :)